# Distinguishing between iphone ibeacon versus a hardware beacon

Tags: ibeacon, estimote

As a beginner in ibeacon technology, I've been trying to get an answer to the following question online but I couldnt find anything that comes close to it!

So here goes...I'm aware that there are hardware ibeacons (eg: by Estimote, Radius Networks etc..) and then there is an iphone which can act as an ibeacon. My question is : When I receive a signal from an ibeacon, is it possible to distinguish whether the signal is from an iphone ibeacon or a hardware ibeacon?

Answer (score 1):

Using the basic `CoreLocation` APIs, all beacons that meet the iBeacon specs will be indistinguishable.  You can make some guesses (e.g. does the beacon use the default Radius Networks or Estimote UUID?) but these won't always be reliable.

If you have access to a proprietary configuration SDK for the hardware beacons (hardware beacons are sometimes configurable via Bluetooth), you might be able to use the `CoreBluetooth` APIs to try to connect to the beacon and determine its manufacturer.  But doing this would require you to write different code for each proprietary hardware beacon you might encounter.  You have to decide if this is worth the trouble (it's a lot of work) especially since you'll never be able to cover all the different hardware beacon types out there.